# Find the volume of the solid generated by revolving the region described below about $x=4$

Tags: calculus

Region bounded by $y=\sqrt{x}$, $y=2$ and $x=0$.

I got the answer as $8\pi$, is that correct?

This was a quiz question and I was marked wrong but I am thinking it was because of how I derived the answer. Is the radius supposed to be $r=\pi(\sqrt{x})^2$ or $4\pi - \pi(\sqrt{x})^2$?

Comment: Much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

If you're doing the integral with horizontal discs, it's
$$\pi\int_0^24^2-(4-x)^2~dy$$
where $4-x$ is the radius of the inner disc you're removing. Since $y=\sqrt x$, $x=y^2$, so the integral is
$$\pi\int_0^24^2-(4-y^2)^2~dy=\int_0^24^2-(4^2-8y^2+y^4)~dy$$
which pops out as $\dfrac{224\pi}{15}$.

[image]

Comment: You're rotating about the line $x=4$. You **don't have** a radius for any $y$ value: you have **two** radii: the outer radius of the disc (which is always 4, going from $x=0$ to $x=4$) and the inner radius (which is $4-x$, going from $x$ to $x=4$). Give me a minute and I'll add a diagram.

Comment: I've done the diagram but @!#% math.SE is displaying its image-loading popup in such a way that the submit button is off-screen and due to it being a scripting abomination, I can't even tab to it.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I see what my error was